# can fortran tell you how many bytes a series of variables is using

Tags: fortran

Say I have a bunch of variables a,b,c

```
integer*4 a
integer*8 b
real*8 c
```

is there a way to determine how many bytes these variables are using without calculating it manually. I have a long list of variables which I need to know the size of for write out purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Fortran 2008 the intrinsic function [`storage_size`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/STORAGE_005fSIZE.html) is the way to go. Also, [`c_sizeof`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/C_005fSIZEOF.html) is useful.

For integers in Fortran 95 you can use [`bit_size`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/BIT_005fSIZE.html).

If you need to declare variables with specific storage size, use the kind constants from module `iso_fortran_env` like `real32`.

Of course, if you use the obsolete and nonstandard declarations as `integer*4` or `real*8` you always know the number of bytes. It is the number after the star (defined as the number of default characters that can be stored in the numeric type).

If you need size of some collection of the variables, you can make a derived type with the same components:

```
type,sequence :: dummy_t
  integer*4 a
  integer*8 b
  real*8 c
end type
type(dummy_t) :: dummy
```

and use `storage_size(dummy)` or use the intrinsic constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gfortran/ifort you can use the sizeof ([gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/SIZEOF.html)) /([IBM](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlf101l.doc%2Fxlflr%2Fsizeof.htm)) command. Not sure about other compilers.